# Vitest with element plus unplugin unknown extension for scss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vitest

I'm trying to run tests using Vitest on a Vue.js app that uses Element Plus registered as a plugin.

If I use `mount` on a component that contains an Element Plus component, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".scss" for /home/projects/vitejs-vite-zcdxhn/node_modules/element-plus/theme-chalk/src/button.scss
```

The issue can be replicated on [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-avqnvz?file=vite.config.js).

My **vite.config.js** file looks like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import ElementPlus from 'unplugin-element-plus/vite';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), ElementPlus({ useSource: true })],
});
```

My **HelloWorld.vue** component looks like this:

```html
<script setup>
import { ElButton } from 'element-plus';
</script>

<template>
  <el-button type="primary">Hello</el-button>
</template>
```

My **HelloWorld.spec.js** looks like this:

```js
import { test, expect } from 'vitest';
import HelloWorld from '../HelloWorld.vue';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

test('hello world test', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld);
  expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Hello');
});
```

The seems to be specifically related to the `ElementPlus({ useSource: true })]` "unplugin" in `plugins` in **vite.config.js** because when I remove that, the problem goes away.

I've reviewed the docs for the various tools (Element Plus, Vite, Vitest), but I've not been able to find how to get this working.

Is there a custom test config that needs to be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation, it fixed by add `deps.inline: ['element-plus']` in vitest config

References:

[Unknown file extension ".css" when using with unplugin-vue-components · Issue #1388 · vitest-dev/vitest · GitHub](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1388)

[Configuring Vitest | Vitest](https://vitest.dev/config/#deps-inline)

Answer (score 1):

```json
vitest: '^0.34.3'
```

> Vitest  "deps.inline" is deprecated. If you rely on vite-node directly, use "server.deps.inline" instead. Otherwise, consider using "deps.optimizer.web.include"

```
deps: {
        optimizer: {
          web: {
            include: ['element-plus']
          }
        }
      }
```

It's works for me

Comment: I came here because I have the same problem with vuetify and get the deprecation warning as well. Unfortunately using `deps.optimizer.web.include:  ['vuetify']` throws a `TypeError: Unknown file extension ".css"`

Comment: For me only using `server.deps.inline:  ['vuetify']` helped.